# "Invalid column index" during a rolling release

Tags: oracle, jruby, release-management

I am dropping a table column in my Oracle database.  My JRuby connection pool appears to be caching metadata and throws an exception upon select:

```
ERROR 12:40:00.408000 pid=1832 tid=bok56 :: Java::JavaSql::SQLException: Invalid column index: 
SELECT  "MY_TABLE".* FROM "MY_TABLE"  WHERE "MY_TABLE"."ID" = :a1
```

Restarting each of my application's several JRuby instances will cause the connections in the pools to grab the correct metadata for the table but I want to do this rollout without downtime.  (During a rolling restart there will be some servers with the old state and some with the new.)

- Is there a way to force the connections in my pools to grab new metadata, either upon `select` or when signaled by the database that the metadata has changed?
- Or is there another strategy for removing an unused column from an active table?

I am not averse to a multi-release (or multi-restart) solution. 
I'd prefer *not* to use Oracle Edition-Based Redifinition™.

While I'm running JRuby on Trinidad, I'm hoping folks with Rails or Java applications will have had to solve this problem as well.

Comment: Using `select *` might not be helping; if you were specifying the columns you were interested in it wouldn't matter if changes were made to any others. Doesn't really help you at this point of course. In Java I'd reset the connection pool but don't know if Ruby has an equivalent.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole!  ActiveRecord is generating the query. I am considering making the query explicit as one option, but if I do a code change I may just use an intermediate view instead.